# Разбор сложного JSON-объекта JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Всем привет. Только начинаю изучать JS и столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть сложный JSON-объект типа

```
{ "values": 
    { "firstName":
         {"type": "String", "value": "foo"},
      "lastName":
         {"type": "String", "value": "bar"},
    }
}
```

Нужно получить значения "value" у FirstName/LastName. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON расшифровывается как JavaScript Object Notation и поддерживается в JavaScript "из коробки" при помощи объекта `JSON`.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var firstName = obj.values.firstName.value;
var lastName = obj.values.lastName.value;
```

Подробнее почитать можно [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).